# Is there a way to apply perspective transformation automatically to parent based on perspective transformation of the child?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm editing an image which needs perspective transformation. I'm interested to apply/emit correction to the whole image/container based the child perspective transformation.

[image: explanatory image]

I could find examples to transform only the area of interest(the black child rectangle).

```py
def four_point_transform(image, pts):

    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))

    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

    return warped
```

I expect to obtain a correct perspective also for the parent object based on the child rectangle transformation as in the dotted contours.

Answer (score 0):

Use the value returned by cv2.getPerspectiveTransform to transform the outer image first. Depending on the result, you may not need to transform the inner black rectangle, as it will get transformed with parent image.

Comment: It worked to corect the image but I get only half of the image. I have changed from:
```python
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight)); 
# to; 
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]));
```
Check the image(just for an ideea): [result unexpected](https://i.imgur.com/Veh00Q8.png)

Comment: Try printing image.shape to see if proper height and width is being passed. Also, is image the black rect or the parent image?

Comment: "image" parameter is the whole image/picture, which contains all the figures(rectangles) and has 1600x1200px). When I print the shapes, are the image sizes.  Somewhere in "dst" variable I need to work, I believe.